# Threads vs cores when threads are asleep

Tags: multithreading

I am looking to confirm my assumptions about threads and CPU cores.

All the threads are the same. No disk I/O is used, threads do not share memory, and each thread does CPU bound work only.

1. If I have CPU with 10 cores, and I spawn 10 threads, each thread will have its own core and run simultaneously.
2. If I launch 20 threads with a CPU that has 10 cores, then the 20 threads will "task switch" between the 10 cores, giving each thread approximately 50% of the CPU time per core.
3. If I have 20 threads but 10 of the threads are asleep, and 10 are active, then the 10 active threads will run at 100% of the CPU time on the 10 cores.
4. An thread that is asleep only costs memory, and not CPU time. While the thread is still asleep. For example 10,000 threads that are all asleep uses the same amount of CPU as 1 thread asleep.
5. In general if you have a series of threads that sleep frequently while working on a parallel process. You can add more threads then there are cores until get to a state where all the cores are busy 100% of the time.

Are any of my assumptions incorrect? if so why?

**Edit**

- When I say the thread is asleep, I mean that the thread is blocked for a specific amount of time. In C++ I would use [sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) *Blocks the execution of the current thread for at least the specified sleep_duration*

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "asleep"?  Are they in a "sleep(...)" call?  Waiting on a lock or notification?  Waiting on I/O?  Any of the above?

Comment: @StephenC In my case I am using https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for Blocks the execution of the current thread for at least the specified sleep_duration.

Comment: All of the assumptions sound correct to me.

Comment: Process and thread scheduling is a part of the operating system so the behavior you describe really depends on OS.

Comment: And you may be competing for CPU / cores with other user / system processes ... and the operating system itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that you are talking about threads that are implemented using native thread support in a modern OS, then your statements are more or less correct.

There are a few factors that *could* cause the behavior to deviate from the "ideal".

1. If there are other user-space processes, they may compete for resources (CPU, memory, etcetera) with your application.  That will reduce (for example) the CPU available to your application.  Note that this will include things like the user-space processes responsible for running your desktop environment etc.
2. There are various overheads that will be incurred by the operating system kernel.  There are many places where this happens including:

   - Managing the file system.
   - Managing physical / virtual memory system.
   - Dealing with network traffic.
   - Scheduling processes and threads.

   That will reduce the CPU available to your application.
3. The thread scheduler typically doesn't do entirely fair scheduling.  So one thread may get a larger percentage of the CPU than another.
4. There are some complicated interactions with the hardware when the application has a large memory footprint, and threads don't have good memory locality.  For various reasons, memory intensive threads *compete* with each other and can slow each other down.   These interactions are all accounted as "user process" time, but they result in threads being able to do less actual work.

---

So:

> 1) If I have CPU with 10 cores, and I spawn 10 threads, each thread will have its own core and run simultaneously.

Probably not all of the time, due to other user processes and OS overheads.

> 2) If I launch 20 threads with a CPU that has 10 cores, then the 20 threads will "task switch" between the 10 cores, giving each thread approximately 50% of the CPU time per core.

Approximately.  There are the overheads (see above).  There is also the issue that time slicing between different threads of the same priority is fairly coarse grained, and not necessarily fair.

> 3) If I have 20 threads but 10 of the threads are asleep, and 10 are active, then the 10 active threads will run at 100% of the CPU time on the 10 cores.

Approximately: see above.

> 4) An thread that is asleep only costs memory, and not CPU time. While the thread is still asleep. For example 10,000 threads that are all asleep uses the same amount of CPU as 1 thread asleep.

There is also the issue that the OS consumes CPU to manage the sleeping threads; e.g. putting them to sleep, deciding when to wake them, rescheduling.

Another one is that the memory used by the threads may also come at a cost.  For instance if the sum of the memory used for all process (including all of the 10,000 threads' stacks) is larger than the available physical RAM, then there is likely to be paging.  And that also uses CPU resources.

> 5) In general if you have a series of threads that sleep frequently while working on a parallel process. You can add more threads then there are cores until get to a state where all the cores are busy 100% of the time.

Not necessarily.  If the virtual memory usage is out of whack (i.e. you are paging heavily), the system may have to idle some of the CPU while waiting for memory pages to be read from and written to the paging device.  In short, you *need* to take account of memory utilization, or it will impact on the CPU utilization.

This also doesn't take account of thread scheduling and context switching between threads.  Each time the OS switches a core from one thread to another it has to:

1. Save the the old thread's registers.
2. Flush the processor's memory cache
3. Invalidate the VM mapping registers, etcetera.  This includes the TLBs that @bazza mentioned.
4. Load the new thread's registers.
5. Take performance hits due to having to do more main memory reads, and vm page translations because of previous cache invalidations.

These overheads can be significant.  According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506564/ this is typically around 1.2 microseconds per context switch.  That may not sound much, but if your application is switching threads rapidly, that could amount to many milliseconds in each second.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, it depends on a number of factors. But in a general sense your assumptions are correct.

**Sleep**

In the bad old days a `sleep()` might have been implemented by the C library as a loop doing pointless work (e.g. multiplying 1 by 1 until the required time had elapsed). In that case, the CPU would still be 100% busy. Nowadays a `sleep()` will actually result in the thread being descheduled for the requisite time. Platforms such as MS-DOS worked this way, but any multitasking OS has had a proper implementation for decades.

10,000 sleeping threads will take up more CPU time, because the OS has to make scheduling judgements every timeslice tick (every 60ms, or thereabouts). The more threads it has to check for being ready to run, the more CPU time that checking takes.

**Translate Lookaside Buffers**

Adding more threads than cores is generally seen as OK. But you can run into a problem with Translate Lookaside Buffers (or their equivalents on other CPUs). These are part of the virtual memory management side of the CPU, and they themselves are effectively content address memory. This is really hard to implement, so there's never that much of it. Thus the more memory allocations there are (which there will be if you add more and more threads) the more this resource is eaten up, to the point where the OS may have to start swapping in and out different loadings of the TLB in order for all the virtual memory allocations to be accessible. If this starts happenging, everything in the process becomes really, really slow. This is likely less of a problem these days than it was, say, 20 years ago.

Also, modern memory allocators in C libraries (and thence everything else built on top, e.g. Java, C#, the lot) will actually be quite careful in how requests for virtual memory are managed, minising the times they actually have to as the OS for more virtual memory. Basically they seek to provide requested allocations out of pools they've already got, rather than each `malloc()` resulting in a call to the OS. This takes the pressure of the TLBs.

Comment: I think the second paragraph is misleading, since modern OS schedulers are almost always designed in such a way that the scheduler will not need to check all (or even any) sleeping threads on every timeslice tick (precisely because, as you point out, doing so would be CPU-inefficient when there are many sleeping threads).  Rather, sleeping threads are kept in a separate data structure entirely, and moved into (or out of) that data structure only when an event occurs to provoke a move.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, it depends largely on what hardware timer resources the underlying hardware has. Ideally the OS would be able to set up a timer for each sleeping thread, the ISR that got fired when the timer expired (the 'event') causing the thread to become re-scheduled. However with limited timer resources the OS has more work to do, the amount depending inevitably on how many sleeping threads there are. A few timers have to be used to raise events that are then processed to determine which threads to reawaken,

Comment: You don't need a separate timer for every sleeping thread; you only need one timer, for the thread that is scheduled to be the next one to wake.  When that timer goes off, you move that thread out of the sleeping-threads list, pop that thread out of the priority-queue of sleeping threads, and reset the timer to go off when the next-thread-to-wake is scheduled to be awoken.  All of those steps are O(1) operations.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, yes, but the management of that priority queue is not zero CPU time per thread. A thread that calls sleep has to be slotted into the right position in that queue. This is a task that takes more time the more threads there are already in the queue. I certainly agree that once all threads are sleeping, and no more are added, that popping off the next thread from the queue is short and essentially deterministic!